Не могу получить доступ к сохраненному файлу
Я сохраняю файл во внутреннее хранилище Android но не могу его найти не через файловый менеджер не через ПК. Помогите пожалуйста

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream

class Register : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)
        setupWindowInsets()

        val loginEditText: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editREGLogin)
        val passwordEditText: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editREGPassword)
        val accessLevelEditText: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editREGDostup)
        val registerButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.regbutton)

        registerButton.setOnClickListener {
            val login = loginEditText.text.toString()
            val password = passwordEditText.text.toString()
            val accessLevel = accessLevelEditText.text.toString()
            val fileContent = "$login,$password,$accessLevel"

            val datasDir = File(filesDir, "DATAS")
            val file = File(datasDir, "Data base.txt")

            try {
                // Создаем папку DATAS, если не существует
                if (!datasDir.exists()) {
                    datasDir.mkdir()
                }

                // Проверяем, существует ли файл перед перезаписью
                if (file.exists()) {
                    // Если файл существует
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Файл уже существует. Данные будут перезаписаны.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                FileOutputStream(file, true).use { fileOutputStream ->
                    fileOutputStream.write(fileContent.toByteArray())
                }

                Toast.makeText(this, "Данные сохранены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Ошибка сохранения данных: ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setupWindowInsets() {
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
    }
}


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Файл с паролями не виден в проводнике - разве должно быть иначе?

Только ваше приложение может видеть файлы в filesDir https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific

Внутреннее хранилище - это не то, где у вас фотографии, музыка и т.п.
Это хранилище приложений, куда они устанавливаются.
Увидеть эти файлы можно не в любом проводнике и только на рутованном девайсе.
Файлы дебаг-версии своего приложения можно увидеть через специальный проводник в студии https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer
